# Magento - Remove Shipping & Handling When Creating Credit Memo

Tags: magento

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to remove the shipping costs when creating a credit memo in Magento programmatically. One of the references I've used is the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo` Class, specifically `setShippingAmount` (e.g. `$this->setData('shipping_amount', 0)`). In fact, when I try and use it the Shipping & Handling line is completely removed from the Credit Memo Totals box, but shipping is calculated anyway...

Another interesting thing that I've noticed: if I assign a value to **'adjustment_negative'** var in the `$data array` (e.g. `$creditmemo = $service->prepareCreditmemo($data)`) it correctly calculates the refund total on the main screen, but if I click on the actual credit memo and look at the totals breakdown, the Adjustment Fee is 0.00 and the totals haven't been changed on the credit memo or the Information view on the main order (Total Refunded is wrong according to my code!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$orderItem = $order->getItemsCollection()->getItemByColumnValue('sku', 'somesku');

$data = array(
    'qtys' => array($orderItem->getId() => 1
    ),
    'shipping_amount' => '0',
    'adjustment_positive' => '0',
    'adjustment_negative' => '10.50'
);

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
$creditmemo = $service->prepareCreditmemo($data);

//$refundToStoreCreditAmount = '3.00';
$refundToStoreCreditAmount = max(
  $refundToStoreCreditAmount, min($creditmemo->getBaseCustomerBalanceReturnMax(), 0));
$refundToStoreCreditAmount = 
  $creditmemo->getStore()->roundPrice($refundToStoreCreditAmount);

//$this->setData('base_shipping_amount', $amount);
//
//$amount = $this->getStore()->roundPrice(
//$amount*$this->getOrder()->getStoreToOrderRate()

$creditmemo->setBaseCustomerBalanceTotalRefunded($refundToStoreCreditAmount);

//$creditmemo->setData('shipping_amount', 0);
//$creditmemo->setData('base_shipping_amount', 0);

$refundToStoreCreditAmount = 
  $creditmemo->getStore()->roundPrice(
  $refundToStoreCreditAmount*$order->getStoreToOrderRate());

$creditmemo->setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded($refundToStoreCreditAmount);
$creditmemo->setCustomerBalanceRefundFlag(true);
$creditmemo->setPaymentRefundDisallowed(true);

$creditmemo->register();

/*
$shipping = 0;
$creditmemo->setShippingAmount($shipping);
$creditmemo->setBaseShippingAmount($shipping);
$creditmemo->setShippingInclTax($shipping);
$creditmemo->setBaseShippingInclTax($shipping);
*/

//$creditmemo->setGrandTotal($creditmemo->getGrandTotal()+$shipping);
//$creditmemo->setBaseGrandTotal($creditmemo->getBaseGrandTotal()+$baseShipping);

//$orderCreditMemoStatusCode = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE;

$saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')->addObject(
  $creditmemo )->addObject ( $order )->save ();

$creditmemo->setEmailSent(true);

try {
  Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($creditmemo)
    ->addObject($order)
    ->save();

  // send email notification
  $creditmemo->sendEmail($notifyCustomer, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
}
  catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
  print_r('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I tried to manually create a credit memo in the backend, on an order I created from my script, and was having the same problem (I couldn't remove/zero-out the shipping amount). I discovered that by adding $order->setBaseShippingAmount('somevalue') when creating my order (I was already using $order->setShippingAmount()), it allowed me to remove shipping later when I created a credit memo! Hope this helps someone...